# Changing bordersize button Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, border-layout

I use WinForm with framework 4.5.2 and I would like to change the border size of a button. Seems rather easy so I go to Properties and set the `BorderSize` in `FlatAppearance` to the desired value. The value in Form.Designer.cs is synchronized automatically. However, nothing happens to the actual border. I can change all properties of the button except for the border size (and color). Is there another property that I need to set first before I can change the border size?

Comment: Please show the code for the adaption of the button

Comment: `aButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; aButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Green; aButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 5;` works for me.

Comment: The FlatAppearance properties can only have an affect if the button is actually flat.  As set by the FlatStyle property.  The other styles mimic standard button styles, the kind that have a prescribed border width.

Comment: `thisButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
thisButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 10` doesn't do anything.

Comment: The `MouseOverBackColor` works fine. Does this property not depend on the `Flatstyle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to make the button a "flat" button by setting its `FlatStyle` property to `Flat`. Otherwise the `FlatAppearance` settings are not used at all, as the button is rendered in System style.

You don't need to do this in code, you can do it in the Properties window directly.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to adjust the button like this:

```
button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 5;
```

If the button is not a "flat" button the border adjustment won't be applied

Comment: The `MouseOverBackColor` which is also under `FlatAppearance` works fine. Does this property not depend on the `Flatstyle`?

Comment: I'm not sure about the visual dependencies of those properties